# Cudafy cannot find cublas, cudafft

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, environment-variables, cublas, cudafy.net

Thanks for reading my thread.

My Cudafy cannot load the **cublas64_55.dll**

I am using Windows 7, VS2012, and CUDA5.5. My **cublas64_55.dll**, **cufft64_35.dll** and etc are all in

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU ComputingTookit\CUDA\v5.5\bin
```

And my environment variable of CUDA_PATH and CUDA_PATH_5.5 are both

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU ComputingTookit\CUDA\v5.5
```

I don't understand why Cudafy cannot find it. Anyone has any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you add your path into your project within VS2012?

Comment: I right clicked project->properties->Reference Path-> then added C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU ComputingTookit\CUDA\v5.5\bin, but that did not work. It is a C# project, and how should I do it? Thanks.

Comment: http://cudafy.codeplex.com/discussions/331743    It might help you. Same problem. Hope this can help

Comment: I simply copied the cublas64_55.dll and cufft64_55.dll to my exe folder, and it works. But I am still wondering how to point to the CUDA directory. Thanks. If you post an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I'm not a pro of Cudafy but anyway at least you find a way by yourself!

Comment: OK if you say so then I will post my solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply copied the **cublas64_55.dll** and **cufft64_55.dll** to my project's /Debug/.exe folder, and it works.